# How to bind-attr for readonly using the input helper (or custom TextField)

Tags: ember.js

I've got a custom input helper like so

```
{{input value=document.description}}
```

I'd like a way to bind another property like readonly or disabled. The problem is that I only want to show readonly in the "finished" state. I can't show even the word readonly/disabled otherwise.

I've tried doing a bind-attr on readonly but it always shows the attribute in html (thus my input is disabled before I have a chance to edit it)

```
{{input value=document.description readonly=document.readonly}}
```

Is it possible to do something like this w/ readonly inside an input helper?

```
{{input value=document.description readonly="controller.disabledInput:readonly"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

While it's not the bind-attr solution I was hoping for, this is what I ended up with

```
{{#if foo.complete}}
  {{foo.description}}
{{else}}
  {{input class="editable" value=foo.description}}
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, does it work if you do something like this:

```
Ember.TextField.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['readonly']
});
```

And then use your original method of binding. One thing I'm not sure of, this might override the already specified attributeBindings [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.3.0/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/text_field.js#L34)

Answer (score 0):

I know the question's old, but I had a similar problem and came across this question.

You're really close with your original method, it just needs two changes. First, remove the quotes around the `readonly` attribute. Then, some properties such as `readonly` and `disabled` expect true/false values - not strings like "readonly" and "disabled". So, here's the working code:

```
{{input value=document.description readonly=document.readonly}}
```

Comment: readonly="false" in HTML makes the input still readonly... am I wrong?

Comment: You are correct. The readonly attribute does not take a value. Its presence alone makes an element readonly. <input readonly /> is all it needs to be read only. <input readonly=true/> or <input readonly=false>, would both yield a readonly input. If you want the element to be editable, you have to remove the readonly attribute.